# Task :react-native-auth0:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED after installing react-native-azurenotificationhub

Tags: react-native, auth0, azure-notificationhub

In my React Native app everything was working fine up until I decided to implement `react-native-azurenotificationhub` to connect my app to Azure Notifications Hub.

My app uses Auth0 for user authentication and up until now, I didn’t have any issues with it.

I’m on the latest version of all the packages, including React Native 0.63.1

I followed the instructions here to install the Azure Notifications Hub package and that’s when all the problems started https://github.com/CatalystCode/react-native-azurenotificationhub/blob/master/docs/android-installation.md

Now, I'm getting the following error:

```
> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

> Task :react-native-auth0:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
42 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 40 up-to-date
C:\Users\sam\source\repos\iQuest\Ingrid Mobile\Time\ingridtime\node_modules\react-native-auth0\android\src\main\java\com\auth0\react\A0Auth0Package.java:13: error: A0Auth0Package is not abstract and does not override abstract method createJSModules() in ReactPackage
public class A0Auth0Package implements ReactPackage {
       ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-auth0:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\sam\source\repos\iQuest\Ingrid Mobile\Time\ingridtime\node_modules\react-native-auth0\android\src\main\java\com\auth0\react\A0Auth0Package.java:13: error: A0Auth0Package is not abstract and does not override abstract method createJSModules() in ReactPackage
```

I've been researching this for the last two days and answers are all over the place and I practically tried all of them to no avail. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Looks like this is something to do with the library. if you check the error, it is inside node_modules and complaining about it. Did you check in the libraries issues column?

Comment: I did check it but didn't see anything wrong -- in all honesty, I don't even know what to look for. The interesting part is that it was all fine before I installed `react-native-azurenotificationhub`

Comment: I know you might have tried this but just want to put it here. How about we delete all the node_modules and Pods from ios folder and do a reinstall of all the libraries and clear the cache and restart the server?

Comment: did you manage to fix this problem? if so, what is the issue?

Comment: No! Still not working!